# How to sort content of an XML file loaded with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, sorting

There is an XML file with a content similar to the following:

```
<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com">
<ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
<DATABASE>My_Database</DATABASE>
<LAYOUT/>
<ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="1">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>19</Age>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="2" RECORDID="2">
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="3" RECORDID="3">
    <Name>Adam</Name>
    <Age>45</Age>
</ROW>
```

I tried to sort the `ROW` tags by the values of `Name` tags using `array_multisort` function:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( 'xml1.xml');
$xml2 = sort_xml( $xml  );
print_r( $xml2 );
function sort_xml( $xml  ) {
    $sort_temp = array();
    foreach ( $xml as $key => $node ) {
        $sort_temp[ $key ] = (string) $node->Name;
}
array_multisort( $sort_temp, SORT_DESC,  $xml );
return $xml;
}
```

But the code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Some SimpleXMLElement methods return arrays but most return SimpleXMLElement objects which implement Iterator. A var_dump() will only show part of of the data in a simplified representation. However it is an object structure, not a nested array.

If I understand you correctly you want to sort the `ROW` elements by the `Name` child. You can fetch them with the `xpath()` method, but you need to register a prefix for the namespace. It returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. The array can be sorted with `usort`.

```
$fResult = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$fResult->registerXpathNamespace('fm', 'http://www.filemaker.com');
$rows = $fResult->xpath('//fm:ROW');

usort(
  $rows,
  function(SimpleXMLElement $one, SimpleXMLElement $two) {
    return strcasecmp($one->Name, $two->Name);
  }
);

var_dump($rows);
```

In DOM that will not look much different, but `DOMXpath::evaluate()` return a `DOMNodeList`. You can convert it into an array using `iterator_to_array`.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('fm', 'http://www.filemaker.com');

$rows = iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('//fm:ROW'));

usort(
  $rows,
  function(DOMElement $one, DOMElement $two) use ($xpath) {
    return strcasecmp(
      $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(Name)', $one),
      $xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(Name)', $two)
    );
  }
);

var_dump($rows);
```

DOM has no magic methods to access children and values, Xpath can be used to fetch them. The Xpath function `string()` converts the first node into a string. It return an empty string if the node list is empty. `normalize-space()` does a little more. It replaces all groups of whitespaces with a single space and strips it from the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the DOM extension, as it is more flexible:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->load('xml1.xml');

// Get the root node
$root = $doc->getElementsByTagName('FMPDSORESULT');
if (!$root->length)
  die('FMPDSORESULT node not found');
$root = $root[0];

// Pull the ROW tags from the document into an array.
$rows = [];
$nodes = $root->getElementsByTagName('ROW');
while ($row = $nodes->item(0)) {
  $rows []= $root->removeChild($row);
}

// Sort the array of ROW tags
usort($rows, function ($a, $b) {
  $a_name = $a->getElementsByTagName('Name');
  $b_name = $b->getElementsByTagName('Name');

  return ($a_name->length && $b_name->length) ?
    strcmp(trim($a_name[0]->textContent), trim($b_name[0]->textContent)) : 0;
});

// Append ROW tags back into the document
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $root->appendChild($row);
}

// Output the result
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

*Output*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com">
  <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
  <DATABASE>My_Database</DATABASE>
  <LAYOUT/>
  <ROW MODID="3" RECORDID="3">
    <Name>Adam</Name>
    <Age>45</Age>
  </ROW>
  <ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="1">
    <Name>John</Name>
    <Age>19</Age>
  </ROW>
  <ROW MODID="2" RECORDID="2">
    <Name>Steve</Name>
    <Age>25</Age>
  </ROW>
</FMPDSORESULT>
```

**Regarding XPath**

You can use `DOMXPath` for even more flexible traversing. However, in this specific problem the use of `DOMXPath` will not bring significant improvements, in my opinion. Anyway, I'll give examples for completeness.

Fetching the rows:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('myns', 'http://www.filemaker.com');

$rows = [];
foreach ($xpath->query('//myns:ROW') as $row) {
  $rows []= $row->parentNode->removeChild($row);
}
```

Appending the rows back into the document:

```
$root = $xpath->evaluate('/myns:FMPDSORESULT')[0];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $root->appendChild($row);
}
```

Comment: You're right, DOM is a lot more flexible and powerful. But I suggest using Xpath in any case. :-)

Comment: @ThW, I like XPath, but in this particular case I don't think it will improve the code significantly.